# How to perform a left outer join between two tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables ShoppingLists and GroceryItems. GroceryItems table contains the ShoppingListId which serves as the foreign key to the ShoppingLists table. I am trying to get all the ShoppingLists and a count of GroceryItems contained in each ShoppingList but I also want to return the ShoppingLists with no grocery items.

```
select s.Title, s.ShoppingListId, count(g.GroceryItemId) AS 'NoOfGroceryItems' FROM ShoppingLists s
JOIN GroceryItems g ON s.ShoppingListId = g.ShoppingListId
```

How can I change the above query to return me the expected result?

If I change the JOIN to LEFT JOIN then it only returns the records where the shopping list does not have any grocery items.

Example data in the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Do not change the question to something different.

Comment: Thanks! When I change the JOIN with LEFT JOIN then I only see the records which do not have any grocery items. I want to show shopping lists with groceryitems and also the ones without the groceryitems.

Comment: The query would be correct; show some example data.

Comment: The original question has been updated with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use left outer join

```
 select s.Title, s.ShoppingListId, count(g.GroceryItemId) AS 'NoOfGroceryItems'        
FROM ShoppingLists s
        left outer join JOIN GroceryItems g ON s.ShoppingListId = g.ShoppingListId
         group by s.Title, s.ShoppingListId
```

You may want to replace the null value with zero when there are no grocery items

Visualize this picture if you ever need to use joins

[image]